# How do I install mosml?

Tags: install-from-source

I need to get [Mosml](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosml.html) (Moskow sml) on to my system for university. I never installed anything that wasn't in the software manager or using wine (read: my console skills are low).

the package is here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/mosml
thing is, I haven't got a clue what to do with it.

So far:

- Tried the mosml.static (a stand-alone toplevel (mosml)) didn't really know what to do with it.
- tried the source files, extracted them and looked in the install.txt, but I don't get the /bin folder and so it seems to be a dead-end..??

Please help if you have a clue. I really need it and its quite urgent.

Comment: if any of these answers answerd your question please accept one of them thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new version of Moscow ML, 2.10. It is available here: [Moscow ML](http://mosml.org)

I have also taken the liberty of creating a `mosml` package in my launchpad PPA. To install it, issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pmunksgaard/mosml
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mosml
```

It should work on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: package available is for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty.

Answer (score 2):

[mosmllib-html.tgz](http://mosmllib-html.tgz)

click on the above link and download the .tar file

Now execute the following commands in order

```
tar zxf file.tar.gz 
ls
cd path-to-software/   //change to the directory --it will be named something like mos something
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the appropriate deb packages:

- [32bit](http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu//pool/multiverse/m/mosml/mosml_2.01-0ubuntu2_i386.deb)
- [amd64](http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu//pool/multiverse/m/mosml/mosml_2.01-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb)

Comment: both links are down