# How do I install mosml on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04

I need to install mosml (Moscow ML) on my system, however I have run into trouble since I changed to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04.

I have previously used the solution provided from this question:  [How do I install mosml?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183720/how-do-i-install-mosml) , but that doesn't seem to work on the latest release.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~kflarsen/+archive/ubuntu/mosml

Comment: Elder Geek, thanks for your response, however I get the following error when I try to update: E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kflarsen/mosml/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Answer (score 1):

It seems the most recent package available in the PPA is for trusty and the last release was 2.10.1 on Aug 28, 2014. So it appears that your options are to downgrade to 14.04 and use the available deb package or take advantage of what is currently available by downloading the source and compiling it after modifying as suggested in the tarball to match your system.

- The Moscow ML [home page](http://mosml.org)
- Moscow ML library [documentation](http://mosml.org/mosmllib/)
- The source files can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/tarball/master)

According to the info in the tarball you can install it as follows:

(1) For a personal installation, move to your home directory, and unpack
     the Moscow ML distribution using

```
     `gzip -dc linux-mos20bin.tar.gz | tar xfv -`
```

This will create a directory ~/mosml with the following subdirectories and notable files

```
 mosml/              readme, install.txt
   bin/          mosml, mosmlc, mosmllex, mosmlyac, camlrunm,
   copyrght/     copyright notices
   doc/          manual.pdf, mosmlref.pdf, mosmllib.pdf, ...
       mosmllib/ HTML-documentation of the Moscow ML library 
   examples/     a few example programs
   lib/          bytecode files, basis library units, 
         and the dynamically loadable libraries
   tools/        mosmldep, Makefile.stub
```

(2) Edit the variables `stdlib` and `mosmlbin` in the scripts
      mosml/bin/mosml &  mosml/bin/mosmlc &  mosml/bin/mosmllex to match your system (you may find `find` useful for this step.

Note: I have not tested this at this point in time, but I assume that this will get you moving n the right direction. If you get stuck, let us know exactly what went wrong and we will attempt to help you resolve the particular problem you ran into.